# how to used c++ variable inside system ( ) function

Tags: c++, sed

I have a .txt file containing 2 columns . I have to search for a pattern in the first column and delete that line from the file that matches .

I have to do this inside a c++ program.

What are the options I could use ?

I though of using a system() function and call sed (which seems efficient). But I'm not sure how to use sed inside system ().
The search pattern is a c++ variable and I'm not sure how to insert it inside sed

```
int pattern;
.
.
.

system ("sed -i '/pattern/d' file.txt");
```

I know it could take this form, but I appreciate any help from you, about how to use c++ variable as  a search pattern inside sed

Comment: You don't insert it into sed, you insert it into a *string*. Does that help?

Comment: "I have to do this inside a c++ program." - um. If that's what the assignment says, then using your C++ program as a glorified shell script to launch `sed` might not count. Full marks for re-using the tools you know about, but they might expect you to write some actual pattern-matching code for yourself in C++, or maybe use a regex library from C++ if the pattern is a regex rather than just a substring you have to find. If you're allowed to use `sed`, then taking to its logical extreme all assignments could be "solved in C++" by passing the command-line arguments straight to a Python script...

Comment: @Steve : Sir, it is not an assignemnt. I'm doing this on my own to get an experience programming in OOPS. The regex library did not cross my mind. I will keep it in mind for future use. Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

assemble in a std::string and then use c_str(). You might find ostringstream (from sstream header) useful for assembling the string.

Comment: Thank you sir. i shall look into this option

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string s = "sed -i '/" + pattern + "/d' file.txt";

system(s.c_str());
```

Comment: You need to use system(s.c_str())